# php simpleXml iteration stops moving to the next element

Tags: php, loops, foreach, simplexml

Can you explain this behavior of foreach iteration of SimpleXmlElement?

This foreach loop works well and iterate through all  elements in specific TAG

```
        $tagName = $jednaPodminka['tag_name'];

        foreach ($xmlelement->{$tagName}->ROW as $oneRow)
        {
            // check all rows in specific tag
            $fld = (object) $oneRow->{(string) $jednaPodminka['field_name']};
            $hodnota = (string) $fld;

            $vysledek = $this->condManager->otestuj($hodnota, $jednaPodminka['value'], $jednaPodminka['cond']);
            if ($vysledek)
            {....}
        }
```

But when I define $rowset before foreach loop and then I use this rowset in the loop, the loop stops iterating through $rowset elements after two iterations, so it iterates throught first two items and then resets and stay on the first element --> effectivelly make this loop endless

```
        $tagName = $jednaPodminka['tag_name'];
        $rowSet = $xmlelement->{$tagName}->ROW;
        $hmr2 = count($rowSet);
        foreach ($rowSet as $oneRow)
        {
            $fld = (object) $oneRow->{(string) $jednaPodminka['field_name']};
            $hodnota = (string) $fld;

            $vysledek = $this->condManager->otestuj($hodnota, $jednaPodminka['value'], $jednaPodminka['cond']);
            if ($vysledek)
            {....}

        }
```

The XMLElement (loaded xml file) looks like this:

```
<TAG>
<ROW>
<FIELD>value</FIELD>
<FIELD>value</FIELD>
<FIELD>value</FIELD>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<FIELD>value</FIELD>
<FIELD>value</FIELD>
<FIELD>value</FIELD>
</ROW>
```

When I use count($rowset) I receive 39. So there are 39  blocks to be checked.

Does it have something to do with calling function ("otestuj") from other object/namespace inside of loop?

Testing on localhost, win, xampp, php 7.0

Comment: It sounds like you're overwriting or manipulating the variable `$rowSet` somewhere else in the code (not shown). Try to create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. For instance, if you think it might be to do with the `otestuj` function call, remove that function call; if the problem persists, remove more code. You should end up either finding the line that's causing the problem, or with a much smaller example that we can run ourselves to help you.